# how to delete not a specific row but a specific field in a row SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

like if table has three columns

1. columnA
2. columnB
3. columnC

just to delete the data of columnA and columnB but not the columnC

since where clause only allows to select a specific row not data in various columns of that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do

```
update table set columnA=null, columnB=null where ...
```

Assuming you get the "where" clause right, this should remove the data from the requested columns.

Comment: you saved my life. thank you! why did i not think of it that way? pressure i guess:-)

Comment: @nadir Probably because you've not gone through the basics of sql